# Efficient 2d interval merging product

Tags: computational-geometry, intervals

Suppose I have two tables of 2d intervals (axis-aligned rectangles) with values attributed to each interval.

```
[d1_start, d1_end), [d2_start, d2_end), value
1,  3,   2, 5,  0.4
3,  9,    2, 5,  0.3
....
```

It is guaranteed that within a table no two rectangles (2d intervals) intersect.

Is there any efficient way to merge the two tables, where if there is overlap in the interval, keep the minimum value, otherwise keep value not changed? The partial overlap would lead to creating new separated records, the non-overlapping part keeps the old value, and the overlapping part keeps the minimum value.

After removing the overlaps, some of the rectangle might not be rectangle anymore, the requirement would be to divide them into smaller rectangles in arbitrary.

I'm thinking of sweep line algorithm that reduces the amount of rectangle in compare, but not sure if there is anything more efficient

Another generative way i was think is to interpolate the intervals with finest grain and evaluate all the interpolated points. Then recombine the points into intervals.